# C++ How To Get Reference To Containing Object?

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have three classes - Album, Track, and PlaylistTrack that extends Track.

Track contains a Time object, and two strings for artist and title.
Album contains a vector of Tracks and a string for title.
PlaylistTrack extends Track in that it contains a pointer to the Album it belongs to.

My question is, how can I get that pointer to the Album that contains it in the class PlaylistTrack?

Comment: Are you talking about the this pointer?

Comment: It would be easier if you post some code with your class hierarchy. You say PlaylistTrack extends Track, and Track has a poiner to the Album. So PlaylistTrack will automatically also contain that pointer, and depending on your access specifier it can also be accessed in PlaylistTrack.

Comment: Doesn't playlist just "contain a pointer to the Album it belongs to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really understand exactly what you are asking, but it sounds like you want to have a way to get the album from a PlaylistTrack.

```
class PlaylistTrack : public Track
{
     public:
         PlaylistTrack(Album * owner){ m_owner = owner; }
         Album* getAlbum(){return m_owner;}
     private:
         Album* m_owner;

}

int main()
{

    Album albumA;
    PlaylistTrack newTrack(&albumA);

    //Now the track knows what album it belongs to, but the album does not own the track yet.
    std::cout << "New Track's Album: " << newTrack.getAlbum.getTitle() << std::endl;

    //Now the album owns this track
    albumA.addTrack(newTrack);

    //The PlaylistTrack constructor could add itself to the album if you wanted to I think.

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, you have understood what I am asking. It is difficult to frame the question correctly as I don't know the proper terminology for what I am trying to understand.  I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Tracks belong to a given Album, and this relationship never change, so the simplest solution would be to pass the pointer of the containing Album object to the constructor of the Track object (or PlaylistTrack, if you like it that way), and save it in the pointer member in the code of the constructor.

Note that PlaylistTracks can refer to the Album object which contains them, but must not delete it by calling `delete` on the member pointer.